# How does one suppress the output of a command?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to run some commands in my shell script however would like to know some method to it returns nothing.

example:

```
#! / bin / bash]
rm / home / user

return: rm: can not lstat `/ home / user ': No such file or directory
```

I would have put the command to run invisibly no return!

Comment: What's all these spaces in between every slash?

Comment: what are you trying to do? To remove a folder use `rm -rf /home/user` but removing a users-folder is probably a bad idea. To remove a file do `rm /home/use/file.txt` Note the lack of spaces. To put teh rm command in a script, the shebang should be `#!/bin/bash`, again, note tha lack of whitespace.

Comment: The error message does not match the code you show. Please don't retype, use cut and paste.

Comment: Are you trying to hide an expected error message, or fix the command so that it doesn't produce an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direct error is coming from incorrect spacing in the path, should be `rm /home/whatever` without spaces in the path, assuming you don't have actual spaces in the dir names (in which case you will need to quote or escape properly)

About suppressing output. Redirecting stdout here is a bit strange.

```
$ touch test.txt
$ rm test.txt > /dev/null 2>&1

^ interactive rm is actually asking if you really want to delete the file here, but not printing the message
```

If you just want to not get error messages, just redirect stderr (file descriptor 2) to /dev/null

```
$ rm test.txt 2> /dev/null
```

or

```
$ rm test.txt 2>&-
```

If you want it to not prompt `do you really want to delete` type messages, use the force flag `-f`

```
$ rm -f test.txt 2> /dev/null
```

or

```
$ rm -f test.txt 2>&-
```

To delete a directory you either want `rmdir` if it's empty or use the recursive `-r` flag, however, this will wipe away **everything** /home/user so you really need to be careful here.

Unless you have it running in `--verbose` mode, I can't think of any case where it needs to close stdout for the `rm` command.

Also as of bash 4, if you want to redirect both stdout and stderr to the same location just use `rm whatever &> /dev/null` or something similar

Answer (score 4):

To suppress the standard output of a command, the conventional way is to send the output to the null device, with `somecommand arg1 arg2 > /dev/null`.  To also suppress error output, standard error can be redirected to the same place:  `somecommand arg1 arg1 > /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Shorter alternative to `> /dev/null 2>&1`: `>& /dev/null` (`&> /dev/null` works, too). Also note that you can persistently redirect streams with `exec` so that subsequent commands need no explicit redirections - see section "Using exec" at http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/io-redirection.html.